# GORM 'where criteria' with multiple many-to-many associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Assuming you have three domain objs defined as such:

```
class Author {
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    static hasMany = [words: Word]
}

class Word {
    String text

    Set<Author> getAuthors() {
        // This throws GenericJDBCException:
        Author.where {
            books.words == this
        }
    }
}
```

Why does `getAuthors()` fail with `ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Parameter "#1" is not set;` but works fine if rewritten using a `Criteria`:

```
public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
    // This works as expected:
    Author.withCriteria {
        books {
            words {
                eq('id', this.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have the syntax of the 'where query' wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the criteria for your query is sort of misleading. `books` and `words` are both associations and you are expecting that `words` to be equal to single instance of the `word` object.

You can try this:

```
def getAuthors() {
    Author.where {
        books{
            words {
                id == this.id
            }
        }
    }.list()
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that there was an implicit spread operation  when comparing collections to entities.  Thanks for clarifying.